# Advanced TPH Mapping to Legacy Database

Tags: entity-framework, orm, ef-code-first, discriminator

I have been working on a project in which I am trying to mold entity framework to an existing FoxPro 2.x database in order to use the data while leaving the tables readable to a legacy application (more details on [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19882588/complex-multi-schema-entity-framework-object-mapping-for-seamless-integration/)).

I've had pretty good luck configuring the `DBContext` to the physical data tables and I have most of my mapping set up. The legacy data structure has a `Bills` table with a unique primary Id key, but all the `LineItems` that can be posted to a bill are stored in a single `Charges` table without a simple primary key.

My question pertains to discriminator mapping in code-first EF.  I am recreating the table as TPH in my data objects, so I have

```
public abstract class Posting
{
    public System.DateTime? Post_Date { get; set; }
    public string Bill_Num { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Pcode { get; set; }
    public string Pdesc { get; set; }
    public decimal? Custid { get; set; }

    public string Createby { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime? Createdt { get; set; }
    public string Createtm { get; set; }

    public string Modifyby { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime? Modifydt { get; set; }
    public string Modifytm { get; set; }

    public string Linenote { get; set; }
    public decimal? Version { get; set; }

    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Batch { get; set; }

    public virtual Billing Bill { get; set; }
    
}

public abstract class Charge : Posting
{
    
}

public class ServiceLine : Charge
{
    public string Chargeid { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Payment> Payments { get; set; }
}

public class ChargeVoid : Charge
{

}

public abstract class Payment : Posting
{

}

public class PaymentLine : Payment
{
    public string Postid { get; set; }
    public string Svc_Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Checkno { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime? Checkdate { get; set; }
}

public class PaymentVoid : Payment
{

}
```

where my mapping strategy so far is along these lines:

```
public class PostingMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Posting>
{
    public PostingMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => new {t.Bill_Num, t.Post_Date, t.Pcode});

        this.Map<Charge>(m => m.Requires("Type").HasValue("C"))
            .ToTable("Charges");
        this.Map<Payment>(m => m.Requires("Type").HasValue("P"))
            .ToTable("Charges");
    }
}
```

I have omitted some fields and mapping classes, but this is the core of it.

Every record has the C/P classification, so this makes everything in the table either a `Charge` or a `Payment`.

Every `Posting` is associated with a `Bill` via `Bill_Num` foreign key.

The `ServiceLine` object is only distinct from `ChargeVoid` objects (which are adjustment entries and no-value information entries associated with a bill) by having values for `Pcode` and `Chargeid` (which is just `Bill_Num` tagged with `01`++).  I have no idea how to model this.

It is very similar for the `Payment` hierarchy as well.

So with my current setup, I have `Postings` which doesn't have a unique key, `Charges` which has a subset of `ServiceLines` with values for `Chargeid` and `Pcode` and a subset with `null`s, and `Payments` similar to `Charges`.  `PaymentLines` are also many-to-one with `ServiceLines` by way of `Pcode` while `PaymentVoids` have `Pcode = null`.

Is there a way I can assign this complex mapping since I can't simply discriminate on `!null`?  On top of that, will EF handle the key assignments once I get the inheritance set up, or am I going to have issues there as well?

Also, if there is a better way to break this object inheritance down, I am all ears.